# Why save method is only executing once in a for loop?

Tags: magento

Script supposed to create 3 entries in database but I am only getting one which is the last entry.

It seems to me save() method is only executing once, but isn't it suppose to run 3 times as well as it is in a for loop?

```
public function saveAction()
{
        $vars = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        var_dump($vars);
        $model = mage::getModel('cevent/cevent');

        for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){

        $data = array(
          'master_customer_id'   =>  $vars['master_customer_id'][$i],
          'customer_id'          =>  'null',
          'email'                =>  $vars['email'][$i],
          'firstname'            =>  $vars['firstname'][$i],
          'surname'              =>  $vars['surname'][$i],
          'address'              =>  $vars['address'][$i],
          'city'                 =>  $vars['city'][$i]
          );


        $model->addData($data);
        $model->save();        
  }
}
```

Posted data from form for database

```
    array
  'master_customer_id' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
  'firstname' => 
    array
      0 => string 'q' (length=1)
      1 => string 'w' (length=1)
      2 => string 'e' (length=1)
  'surname' => 
    array
      0 => string 'q' (length=1)
      1 => string 'w' (length=1)
      2 => string 'e' (length=1)
  'email' => 
    array
      0 => string 'q' (length=1)
      1 => string 'w' (length=1)
      2 => string 'e' (length=1)
  'address' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Invercagille' (length=12)
      1 => string 'Invercagille' (length=12)
      2 => string 'Invercagille' (length=12)
  'city' => 
    array
      0 => string 'q' (length=1)
      1 => string 'w' (length=1)
      2 => string 'e' (length=1)
```

DB showing only one entry

[image]

Please suggest something or if there is any other way around. Thank you

Comment: Isn't the 'for' closing } missing?

Comment: sorry just edited. it's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento's ORM uses `save()` for both create and update operations. The presence of a primary key is what the resource model layer uses to determine whether to perform an insert or update. When your object data is saved during the first iteration it is inserted, but the autoincrement primary key is then set on the instance referenced by `$model`, after which you will only get updates. You can unset the data or re-instantiate the class in the `for` loop and accomplish multiple inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop creates an object, and all the next are updating this same object.

You must reset your object in each loop in order to create a new one.

Instead of using `object->addData()`, use `object->setData()` which will replace all your data with the new one (and, in background, delete the primary_key of the previous saving that is stored in your object data).